# What is the difference between !!msg.message and msg?.message?

Tags: javascript

Difference between  `!!msg.message && msg.message` and `msg?.message` ?

First one is when msg is `undefined` msg.message will not be executed.

What is the meaning of second ?

Comment: Actually, in the first one, if `msg` is `undefined`, it will throw an exception.

Comment: Why is the question down voted ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called "optional chaining" and you can read about it [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) in the context of Babel. There is also the plain JavaScript [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), and as MDN states:

> This is an experimental technology